# How do you lookup a particular pandas dataframe column value in a reference table and copy a reference table value to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a reference table that I imported into a dataframe(df2) from a .csv.  It's 3 columns and around 400 rows.  I have another dataframe (df) that has many columns and rows.  I am looking to lookup a value from the reference table and add it to the appropriate column in df.

The data format for the reference table:

```
MANUF   PRODTYPE        PRODCODE
 
ALPHA       1           ALPHA1
ALPHA       2           ALPHA2
BETA        1           BETA1
BETA        2           BETA2
DELTA       1           DELTA1
DELTA       2           DELTA2
```

The dataframe (df) is set up like this:

```
MANUF    PRODTYPE    SERIALNO   PRODCODE    INVENTORY   
ALPHA       1        00001                      5
ALPHA       2        00001                      3
BETA        1        00001                      4
DELTA       1        00001                      8
ALPHA       2        00002                      3
BETA        1        00002                      4
DELTA       2        00001                      9
DELTA       2        00002                      9
DELTA       1        00002                      8
BETA        2        00001                      12
ALPHA       2        00003                      3
```

I am trying to populate PRODCODE in df with the appropriate value based on MANUF and PRODTYPE in the reference table.

I tried:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, how='left')
```

and

```
df3 = df2.merge(df, how='left')
```

but both gave me either inaccurate or incomplete merges.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to work in your case:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

data1 = StringIO("""MANUF;PRODTYPE;PRODCODE
ALPHA;1;ACME1
ALPHA;2;ACME2
BETA;1;BETA1
BETA;2;BETA2
DELTA;1;DELTA1
DELTA;2;DELTA2
""")
df1 = pd.read_csv(data1, sep=";")
print(df1)

data2 = StringIO("""MANUF;PRODTYPE;SERIALNO;PRODCODE;INVENTORY   
ALPHA;1;00001;5
ALPHA;2;00001;3
BETA;1;00001;4
DELTA;1;00001;8
ALPHA;2;00002;3
BETA;1;00002;4
DELTA;2;00001;9
DELTA;2;00002;9
DELTA;1;00002;8
BETA;2;00001;12
ALPHA;2;00003;3
""")
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2, sep=";")
print(df2)

df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['MANUF', 'PRODTYPE'], how='left')
print(df3)
```

Result:

```
    MANUF  PRODTYPE  SERIALNO  PRODCODE_x  INVENTORY    PRODCODE_y
0   ALPHA         1         1           5           NaN      ACME1
1   ALPHA         2         1           3           NaN      ACME2
2    BETA         1         1           4           NaN      BETA1
3   DELTA         1         1           8           NaN     DELTA1
4   ALPHA         2         2           3           NaN      ACME2
5    BETA         1         2           4           NaN      BETA1
6   DELTA         2         1           9           NaN     DELTA2
7   DELTA         2         2           9           NaN     DELTA2
8   DELTA         1         2           8           NaN     DELTA1
9    BETA         2         1          12           NaN      BETA2
10  ALPHA         2         3           3           NaN      ACME2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  For some reason that's only pulling in PRODCODE for ~1200 of the ~20K records.  The rest are blank in the merge and now the file has two columns PRODCODE_x and PRODCODE_y with PRODCODE_x being completely blank and PRODCODE_y having the 1200 values.  This was the same result I got when I ran:

df3 = df2.merge(df, how='left')

Comment: I did update my answer. Does the code above work for you?

Comment: It does kind of.  Thank you.  However, maybe I oversimplified my question.  Ultimately the primary key I will be focused on is serial number and there are about 30 different columns associated with each and growing.  I'm trying to find a way to do this without over complicating since the dimensions of the data will continue to grow over time.

Basically I'm trying to accomplish this with the data range being df2

https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: did you have a look at my solution? or is there the same problem in the real complicated data?

Answer (score 0):

Another way without `merge` would be this:

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['MANUF', 'PRODTYPE'])
output = df2.combine_first(df1.set_index(['MANUF', 'PRODTYPE'])).reset_index()
print(output)

    MANUF  PRODTYPE  INVENTORY PRODCODE  SERIALNO
0   ALPHA         1          5   ALPHA1         1
1   ALPHA         2          3   ALPHA2         1
2   ALPHA         2          3   ALPHA2         2
3   ALPHA         2          3   ALPHA2         3
4    BETA         1          4    BETA1         1
5    BETA         1          4    BETA1         2
6    BETA         2         12    BETA2         1
7   DELTA         1          8   DELTA1         1
8   DELTA         1          8   DELTA1         2
9   DELTA         2          9   DELTA2         1
10  DELTA         2          9   DELTA2         2
```

Used Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'MANUF': {0: 'ALPHA',
  1: 'ALPHA',
  2: 'BETA',
  3: 'BETA',
  4: 'DELTA',
  5: 'DELTA'},
 'PRODTYPE': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2},
 'PRODCODE': {0: 'ALPHA1',
  1: 'ALPHA2',
  2: 'BETA1',
  3: 'BETA2',
  4: 'DELTA1',
  5: 'DELTA2'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'MANUF': {0: 'ALPHA',
  1: 'ALPHA',
  2: 'BETA',
  3: 'DELTA',
  4: 'ALPHA',
  5: 'BETA',
  6: 'DELTA',
  7: 'DELTA',
  8: 'DELTA',
  9: 'BETA',
  10: 'ALPHA'},
 'PRODTYPE': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 1,
  9: 2,
  10: 2},
 'SERIALNO': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 1,
  7: 2,
  8: 2,
  9: 1,
  10: 3},
 'INVENTORY': {0: 5,
  1: 3,
  2: 4,
  3: 8,
  4: 3,
  5: 4,
  6: 9,
  7: 9,
  8: 8,
  9: 12,
  10: 3}})
```

Comment: It's probably not the most efficient way but I was able to get it to work by running an iteration loop and using match.  Thank you for the help!